# convert 1 column to several columns

Tags: linux

I am using this command:

```
wc -l */* >> file
```

which creates a file in current directory of all the appropriate info from the subdirectories. My problem is that it pastes the data in 1 long column. Can I have it paste the data in several columns?

Answer (score 0):

The [pr](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pr&sektion=1) command may help.

For example:

```
   wc -l */* |  pr -2 -t
```

will give your output in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

The 'paste' command is probably what you're looking for. An example:

```
$ cut -d: -f1 /etc/group|paste - - - -
root    bin     daemon  sys
adm     tty     disk    lp
mem     kmem    wheel   mail
uucp    man     games   gopher
video   dip     ftp     lock
audio   nobody  users   dbus
...
```

There I used cut to get a list of the names in my /etc/group file, then used paste to print it 4-up. However many hyphens you list on the paste command line, paste will gobble up another line and put it in that column.